# How can I write equation like this

Tags: equations

I want to create an equation like this 
[image]

```
\begin{multline*}
Time = a + b * h1(x) + c * h2(x) + d * h3(x) + e * h4(x) \\
 where \ \ h\textsubscript{1,2,3,4}(x) = 
    \Bigg\{
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    x  & x > 0 \\
    0  & x $\leq$ 0 
    \end{tabular}
\end{multline*}
```

it looks like this without equation number
[image]

any hints?

Answer (score 4):

Your equation

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
\mathrm{Time} = a + b \times h_1(x) + c \times h_2(x) + d \times h_3(x) + e \times h_4(x) \\
 \text{where}\ \ h_{1,2,3,4}(x) = 
    \begin{cases}
    x  & x > 0 \\
    0  & x \leq 0 
    \end{cases}
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Strongly** recommended version

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
We have
\[\mathrm{Time} = a + b \times h_1(x) + c \times h_2(x) + d \times h_3(x) + e \times h_4(x)\]
where 
\[h_{1,2,3,4}(x) = 
    \begin{cases}
    x  & x > 0 \\
    0  & x \leq 0 
    \end{cases}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
We have
\[\mathrm{Time} = a + b \times h_1(x) + c \times h_2(x) + d \times h_3(x) + e \times h_4(x)\]
where 
\[h_{1,2,3,4}(x) = 
    \begin{cases}
    x  & \text{if $x > 0$} \\
    0  & \text{otherwise} 
    \end{cases}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here there is another proposal. There are many possibilities to better write your formula.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
  \mathrm{Time} = & \, a + b \ast h_1(x) + c \ast h_2(x) + d \ast h_3(x) + e \ast h_4(x) &\nonumber\\
  \mathrm{where} & \,\ h_{1,2,3,4}(x) = 
    \begin{cases}
    x  & x > 0 \\
    0  & x \leq 0 
    \end{cases} 
\end{flalign}

\begin{flalign}
  \mathrm{Time} = & \, a + b \cdot h_1(x) + c \cdot h_2(x) + d \cdot h_3(x) + e \cdot h_4(x) &\nonumber\\
  \mathrm{where} & \,\ h_{1,2,3,4}(x) = 
    \begin{cases}
    x  & x > 0 \\
    0  & x \leq 0 
    \end{cases} 
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `h_1`, not `h1` etc  :-) . I also suspect that `*` means multiplication. You my suggest to OP that for multiplication usually we not write special symbol (after grammar school at least)

Comment: @Zarko I only saw the first image. I am blinded :-)